# How to fix 'APK is using permissions that require a privacy policy: (android.permission.CAMERA)' error in play console

Tags: flutter, camera, google-play-console

I'm setting my flutter app to upload on play console but it shows error-
"Your APK or Android App Bundle is using permissions that require a privacy policy: (android.permission.CAMERA)."
  Even though I am not using permission for camera in my manifest file.

main/manifest file-

```
<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="Motive Booster"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
             until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
             there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
             defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
            android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: chek once Your app dependencies like Gallery or any libraries may using.First Find in your Project

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

One of your dependencies must be bringing the camera permission.

To remove it, you can add this to your manifest:

```xml
<manifest ... xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" tools:node="remove"/>
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: It gives error on build -  What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateReleaseBuildConfig'.
> Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\Azhan Khan\AndroidStudioProjects\simple_motivation\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml